# Lisp: Difference of List2 to List1

Tags: list, lisp

I am fairly new to lisp and trying to breakdown this problem with getting the difference of two lists. 
I need to find all the numbers in list 2 that are not in list 1

Looking to get `(diff list1 list2)`...Example would be that `(diff '(4 5 6 8 9) '(1 2 4 6 8 9))` Return would be `(1 2)`

What I have so far

```
(defun diff (l1 l2) 
  (cond ((null l1) nil) 
        ((member (first l1) l2) (diff(rest l1) l2)) 
        (t (cons (first l2) (diff (rest l2) l1)))))


(defun diff1 (l1 l2)
  (cond ((null l1) nil) 
        ((member (first l2) l1) (diff (rest l2) l1)) 
        (t (cons (first l2) (diff (rest l2) l1)))))
```

These are two different methods I have tried but cannot seem to get it return List 2 over list 1.

Comment: Please do not delete your question after someone has taken the time to answer it.

Comment: This question should be removed because it is predicated on a typo and will have no usefulness for future searchers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the last line of `diff`:

```
(defun diff (l1 l2)
  (cond ((null l2) nil) 
        ((member (first l2) l1) (diff l1 (rest l2))) 
        (t (cons (first l2) (diff l1 (rest l2))))))
```

Note that the bug is obvious once you format your code properly :-)

Also, the function you are looking for is already present in Common Lisp under the name [`set-difference`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set_di.htm).

Comment: I tried this and was not getting the return I am looking for. Set-difference works for the difference between list1 and list2. I am looking for the reversal of that. List2 difference to list1. While still following the pattern (diff list1 list2)

Comment: @user2899108: okay, fixed for your reversed arg order

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. The result I am getting from this code is (1 2 5 4 6 8 9). It should be just (1 2). As 1 and 2 are the only numbers different compared to one. Still stuck....

Comment: @user2899108: try now please

Comment: What are the restrictions that prohibit `(defun your-diff (list1 list2) (set-difference list2 list1))`?